# can a search for the individuals in a group display notes instead of address, etc

Tags: contacts, groups

I would like to be able to read the notes for a group of individuals when I am looking at the resulting list of contacts from a search.

Answer (score 1):

That might be a little visually difficult if they have 30 notes, but here's two options:

1. At the search results screen select some or all and then from the actions dropdown at the top of the list choose Export.
2. In the export screens choose "select fields for export".
3. When choosing the fields, include the field called "Note(s)".

If you want it on the screen instead of an export, and you're ok with **only seeing the first note** you can do like so:

1. Go to Administer - Customize Data and Screens - Profiles.
2. Click on the Reserved tab.
3. Click on "Fields" on the right side of the screen next to the Summary Overlay one.
4. Click Add Field.
5. For field name, select Contacts , and then the one called "Note".
6. Click save.
7. Do a search and in the search results list, if you hover over the contact icon in the 2nd column you'll see the first note in the popup that comes up.

Answer (score 0):

I'd originally thought that Demerit's solution only showed one note. But testing again, it does have all notes but in one row comma separated, which is confusing, particularly with multi-line notes. Also the subjects are not included. I don't think there is a perfect solution!

If you had a very particular thing you wanted to do, you might consider a multi-value custom field, which you can view in certain reports (something derived from Constituent Summary works) but beware that there are other limitations of multi-valued custom fields so think it all through.

I'd thought that you might be able to use a report instead of a search (based on my idea above) but you can't get the notes in a report!

Comment: Hi @Mick Kahn my tests showed the export option does include all notes.

Comment: @Demerit, sorry you are right - it does include all the text of the notes (but not the subjects). I'd expected them to be separate rows in the spreadsheet and hadn't spotted that they had been run together (they are comma separated, but this is easily confused with commas in the text) because some of my notes were many lines (imported from elsewhere, so some odd characters as well). So your answer is useful in some circumstances. Will adjust my comment above. My suggestion above still may be better in some situations as it can include the equivalent of subject and uses separate rows on export